# JS: How to use localStorage() with querySelectorAll (multiple input-fields)?

Tags: javascript, html

I got a question concerning JS localStorage()-function in connection with the querySelectorAll(). Here's my code:

```
const comments = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="submit"]'));      

comments.forEach(comment =>
{
  comment.addEventListener('click', custom_text);                                             
});

function custom_text() {
  let inputs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]'));
  let textblocks = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div.comment_form'));  
  let length = inputs.length;                                                                 
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {                                                          
    if (inputs[i].value !== "") {                                                             
      let text = document.createTextNode("User says: " + inputs[i].value);          
      let para = document.createElement("div");   
      localStorage.setItem("comment" + i, inputs[i].value);
      let test = localStorage.getItem("comment" + i);
      console.log(test);                                    
      para.appendChild(text);                                                                 
      textblocks[i].appendChild(para);                                                        
      inputs[i].value = "";                                                                   
    }
  }
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="d-flex">
   <input class="form-control ms-2 border-0" type="text" name="commenttext" placeholder="Kommentieren ..." size="50">
    <input class="btn btn-link m-2 text-decoration-none" type="submit" name="comment" value="post">
</div>

<div class="ms-2">
     <span href="#" class="text-decoration-none text-black-50 custom_font">All comments:</span>
     <div class="fw-lighter comment_form">
     </div>
</div>
```

Keep in mind that this is not the only comment-form, as there are a lot of posts with the exact html-tags on the site.
I would like to save every comment with localStorage - my problem was, that I could just save one comment per comment-field, so if I would post another one, the last one was overwritten... Also I do not just want to console.log it, I want it to be child of "para", which also won't work.

I hope I made my question clear enough and I would be happy if someone could help me :)

Comment: Give the whole comment-form an unique id, so that the combination of the comment-form id and the comment `i` will be unique (e.g. `\`comment-${id}-${i}\``). When the user click the submit button, search for it's parent comment-form to get the id

Comment: So you know `forEach` will work on a node list without the need for `Array.from`.